# How to delete column name of single column of data frame?

Tags: r

I am working on `data set` for analysis.

I have to remove column name of single variable of data frame in `r`.

I have used `colnames(df)<-NULL` function,it removes all colnames of dataframe

The excepted output is:

[image]

Comment: `colnames(df)[2]<-NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the expected output, but maybe this is what you're looking for

```
colnames(df)[i] <- NA
```

'i' is the column location (for example 1,2,3 etc)